# Как создать пустой объект определенного типа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в питоне создать пустой объект определенного типа?

Например, функция принимает параметр `x` неизвестного типа, и надо создать в функции локальную переменную `y` типа `x`. Если `x` будет списком, то создать пустой список (`y=[]`), если кортежем -- пустой кортеж (`y=()`), и т.д..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не существует универсального способа создать объект произвольного типа, но если конструктор типа вызывается без аргументов, можно сделать так

```
y = type(x)()
```

```
>>> type([1,2,3])()
[]
>>> type((1,2,3))()
()
>>> type({1,2,3})()
set()
```

Comment: Спасибо. А раз все наследуется от `Object`, нет какой-нибудь способа через него типа фабрики объектов, но чтобы аргументы можно было передавать?

Comment: @user354362 От `object` наследуются все классы, это делу не поможет. Если, например, `range` обязательно требует минимум один аргумент, то без него создать вменяемый экземпляр `range` не получится, да и незачем. Но для большинства контейнеров такой способ подойдет. Ну или можно проверять тип аргумента с помощью `type()` или `isinstance()`, и делать соответствующие выводы.

Comment: Это же сработает для `int`, `str`, `dict`, `bool`, `bytes`, `complex`, `float`, `frozenset`, `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос сложный и нужно разобраться с присвоением в python и имеющимися типами. Легко запутаться и прийти непонятно к чему))

`x = None` - `x` это пустая переменная?

`y = 0` - `y` это пустой `int`?

`z = ''` - `z` это пустой `str`?

Для решения вашей задачи используйте в коде:

```
x = [1, 2]
i = isinstance
t = {i(x, list): list(), i(x, set): set(), i(x, tuple): tuple()}.setdefault(True, None)
print t
# []
```